# Upload 50 millions of data to Google App Engine data store

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to find the best way to transfer my huge data to google app engine datastore. We are java developers and it would be great if you can suggest the solutions around Google App Engine Java.

I have seen few solutions like google app engine pipeline, map reduce and tried them but nothing works. Is there any real solution that works?

Thanks,
Ramesh.V

Comment: Why don't you use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage)? Unlimited space, unlimited object size limit and a [GAE Java API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview).

Comment: Google Cloud Storage is not a database to store data, its a file storage, i want to move my database data, does Google Cloud Storage help me?

Comment: Yeah, it's not a database. But in my opinion a databse is not the right place to store (single) hughe data. Thats also the reason why you only can store max. 1Mb objects in the GAE Datastore. If you really want to use a Database instead of a file storage system, maybe [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/) with the [GAE Java SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide) is what you are searching for.

Comment: How big is a single object (average)? Kb? Mb? Gb?

Comment: Sorry its not a single file, i mean to say 50 million records in my existing database, in different tables. And i need to run SQL queries on it.

Comment: Then my last idea is [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/). But i made the experience that the communication speed between GAE and GCS is not that good.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your suggestions, but GCS is a mysql, i need something more better like gae datastore.

Answer (score 1):

What I did, split them into files of max 32MB? Upload them along with the backend source code and write a program on backend to fetch the data to datastore records... Mind you, each record has a maximum size of 1MB.

Comment: DO you mean to read a file in the source code and insert it into to datastore?

Comment: Oh actually, I have to correct my answer. What I did was to write a program to handle file upload via HTTP POST, each file uploaded via HTTP POST are <32MB and the data is processed immediately to the datastore.

Comment: @LawrenceMok How did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the best way, but have you looked at GAE/J's Remote API for Java?

Comment: GAE/J Remote API has no special stuff for uploading huge data, its regular API call...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Google BigQuery?

https://cloud.google.com/products/big-query

[Here's a howto for the data transfer](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/ingestioncookbook#cloudstorageordirectupload)

Comment: Sorry, Google big query is not a datastore, but a platform to perform SQL-like queries on big structured files, from the datastore, we can export a file to big query, then perform SQL through the rest API from our GAE application (for instance to display stats, dashboards), but not the other way round